# How to readjust image size when pasting into a table in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am trying to paste images into a table so the images readjust to the cell size.
I have disabled "Automatically Resize to Fit Contents", I have selected "Specify Height - Exactly" and "Fixed Width". While the cell size is fixed, the image is bigger than the cell itself. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't paste the image into the cell, pasting doesn't initiate the resizing function. Instead use the Insert > Pictures function, which also means that the image file must already exist on a disk somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Wish there was a more direct way, though.

Comment: A little more direct way after a clipboard based copy would be a macro that Inserted the clipboard content. The resize trigger to Word is the Insert function. You would then just have to remember the custom keystroke you assigned to running the macro versus Ctrl + V. This also would only work in a Windows version of Word. Clipboard control is lacking in Mac Word 2016 and non-existent in prior versions.

Answer (score 0):

### Dirty Hack with PowerPoint

For all the ones that had issues of even spacing and resizing: consider not using a table but rather use the neat aligning lines in PowerPoint! It helps a lot and you can simply copy paste it to Word after. Credits to Adi ;).

[image: Image Aligning]